# Fullcalendar: how to know in which cell I am dropping an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am creating the calendar where I can drop events from external list.

I took as example this sample - [external-dragging](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.5.0/demos/external-dragging.html).

I want to add specific logic that **user can add only one event per day**.

So for preventing dropping to 'filled' cell I am trying to use [dropAccept](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/dropAccept/) method in the next way.

```
dropAccept: function (item) {
    return [my condition];
},
```

I can get item that I am dropping from `item` element, I can get calendar's events but I can't get a cell (or a date) where I am putting my item.

How could I get a cell/date where I am dropping item?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this in another way.

1. I set all events as all day by default
2. I forbade an event overlapping

My code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    allDayDefault: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drop](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/) function of full calendar.
Here is parameters

```
function( date, jsEvent, ui ) { }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I am not sure that I could prevent dropping in this function.

Comment: your issue: I can get item that I am dropping from item element, I can get calendar's events but I can't get a cell (or a date) where I am putting my item.

Solution: function( date, jsEvent, ui ) { }
first parameter of function named 'date' will give you date and time where you are dropping external events.